# limit of the sum of two sequences, one of which tends to $-\infty$ and the other is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I am trying to construct a proof for the sum of two sequences ($a_n +b_n$ tending to $-\infty$), where one of which ($a_n$) tends to $-\infty$ and the other ($b_n$) is given as bounded above.

From this I have said that as $b_n$ is bounded above, by definition $\exists U \in R$ s.t $b_n<U \forall n \in N_+$

Then I am not sure how to proceed but I am considering the following:

Let $\exists N\in N_+$ s.t $\forall n>N$, $a_n<$ some $L \in R$, from this we can go on to say that by the sum rule $n>N \implies(a_n + b_n) <L+U$ and so we have constructed the definition of $lim(a_n+b_n) =-\infty$ as we can take $L$ to be an arbitrarily large negative number.

I feel like I am missing a nicer way of expressing the above; any help is appreciated

Comment: Given any $L\in \mathbb{R}$, by definition of divergence to $-\infty$ you can find $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $a_n<L-U$ then $a_n+b_n < L-U+U=L$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of divergence to $-\infty$, for any $L_1$ you can find an $N_1$ s.t. $\forall n > N$, you have $a_n < L_1$.

To prove $a_n + b_n$ diverges $-\infty$, you need to show that for any $L$, there exists an $N$ s.t for all $n > N$, you have $a_n + b_n < L$. Well by divergence of $a_n$, if we let $L_1 = L - U$, then we can find an $N$ s.t $\forall n > N$, you have $a_n < L_1 = L - U$ and thus $a_n + b_n < L - U + U = L$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n$ be upper bounded by $c$. Let $a_n \to -\infty$, i.e., for each $k$, $a_n<k$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. In particular, $a_n<k-c$ for all $n$ large. Hence $a_n+b_n<k$ for all $n$ large, i.e., $a_n+b_n \to -\infty$.