# Difference of limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be sequences where $x_n\to a$ $(a\in\mathbb{R})$ and $y_n\to \infty$. How can I show that $x_n-y_n\to -\infty$?

I'm guessing I have to use an $\varepsilon$-N-definition of convergent sequences but I don't know how to (or if I should) combine the definitions of convergence and divergence.

Comment: **[Hint]** : While trying to prove some algebraic properties of sequences that involves addition, think of how you can use the triangle inequality.

Comment: $x_n-y_n<-N$ if $x_n<a+1$ and $y_n >N+a+1$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2069562/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to show that for every $M<0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$$\forall n>N\quad x_n-y_n<M$$

For that, you can pick an $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$, for every $n>N_1$ and some $\epsilon>0$. Then pick an $N_2$ that is high enough to make $x_n-y_n<M$. What do you need $y_n$ to be? Notice that it can be as big as you want for high enough $N_2$, so use that. Since $M$ is arbitrary, you will have proven your claim.

Comment: Is it necessary to find specific values for $N_1$ and $N_2$ or can I just say that those values exist?

Comment: You can just say that they exist, in fact you can't give values for them. Convergence by itself does not tell you how fast they converge so, from the conditions that you gave, you can't really specify specific values for $N_1$ and $N_2$